# A filter to apply only if only one item from two other filters are selected

Tags: tableau-api

I have two filters for **WeekNumber** and **Employee** (name). I also have a column that shows the `SUM` of hours the employee has worked. Let us call it **SumHours**.

What I want to do is to specify the employees who have overworked, which is

> if the number of weekly hours is more than `38`.

If the condition applies I'd like to highlight them by adding a background color to their row.

Adding the above filter to the entire table is not a problem. What I want to do is for this filter to appear *only* if (1) one week and (2) one employee have been selected. Because otherwise the calculated field will highlight the employee if they have overworked *in average*.

How can I create a condition in my calculated field so that a condition is checked in two different places? I have found the `SIZE()` function but then we should also select the option **Compute Using...** to assign it to a specific filter. But apparently one cannot do that to two filters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, I think a level-of-detail calculation might do the trick. This is pseudo-code, you will need to adjust for your dimension names. With LOD, you are getting the value of the hours worked per employee and week, regardless of which dimensions you have in your rows or columns.

`if {FIXED Employee, WeekNumber : sum(HoursWorked)} > 38 then "Highlight" end`

Then add this calculated field on the color marks card.

More about level-of-detail calcs can be found in [Tableau's online help](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html).